# Increment by 1 for every unique change in column [in R]

Tags: r, unique

I am a newby to R and I've been searching and trying out for about a week, wrestling with this task. I need to create a new variable that increments by 1 with every unique value of a given variable - in this case 'spec' or 'speccode', whatever works. As my dataset of species is too big, I created a test dataset to show my problem:

```
dat<-as.Date(c("1-5-2012", "1-5-2012", "1-6-2012", "1-7-2012", "1-9-2012", 
                   "1-9-2012", "1-9-2012", "1-10-2012", "1-10-2012", "1-1-2013"), "%d-%m-%Y")
spec<-c("Ae. gen", "Ae. gen", "cpk", "Cul ann", "Anoph", "Anoph", "cpk", "Anoph", "Cul ann", "Ae. gen")
speccode<-c(1, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1)
test.df<-data.frame(dat, spec, speccode)
test.df
```

I would like to add a new variable "specrec" that counts every unique value consecutively and only adds 1, in case the value is different from every value that came before. Like that:

`dat    spec speccode specrec
1  2012-05-01 Ae. gen        1       1
2  2012-05-01 Ae. gen        1       1
3  2012-06-01     cpk        4       2
4  2012-07-01 Cul ann        5       3
5  2012-09-01   Anoph        3       4
6  2012-09-01   Anoph        3       4
7  2012-09-01     cpk        4       4
8  2012-10-01   Anoph        3       4
9  2012-10-01 Cul ann        5       4
10 2013-01-01 Ae. gen        1       4`

The best approximation I could code was

```
r = rle(test.df$speccode)
test.df$specrec<-rep(seq_along(r$lengths), r$lengths)
test.df
```

but it counts everytime the value changes, independent if it is unique or not.

I need this new variable to create a species discovery curve. I know about the vegan package and the corresponding functions. However, I got neither of it working with my dataset with over 21.000 observations from a nearly similar number of "sites".

Every help is highly appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with `cumsum` of logical vector created with `duplicated` on the 'speccode'

```
library(dplyr)
test.df %>% 
    mutate(specrec = cumsum(!duplicated(speccode)))
#           dat    spec speccode specrec
#1  2012-05-01 Ae. gen        1       1
#2  2012-05-01 Ae. gen        1       1
#3  2012-06-01     cpk        4       2
#4  2012-07-01 Cul ann        5       3
#5  2012-09-01   Anoph        3       4
#6  2012-09-01   Anoph        3       4
#7  2012-09-01     cpk        4       4
#8  2012-10-01   Anoph        3       4
#9  2012-10-01 Cul ann        5       4
#10 2013-01-01 Ae. gen        1       4
```

---

Or the same logic in `base R`

```
test.df$specrec <- cumsum(!duplicated(test.df$speccode))
```

---

The function `rle` checks whether the adjacent elements are the same or not and not on the whole column